# Background color breaking when loop piped into lemonbar (Arch)

Tags: arch-linux, i3, panel, lemonbar

I have a setup where I am piping the time into lemonbar on a loop. Essentially I have three sections of the bar with two different background colours. Everything works fine until the time gets piped in on the right hand side. At that point the background colour of the time over wrights the background colour I had set. Here are some screenshots to help explain what I am talking about.

This is what I want:
[image: GOOD]

This is what I get:
[image: BAD!!]

Config files: https://github.com/Marcel-Robitaille/dotfiles

I am using the kernel 4.3.3-3-Arch with i3 and compton.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by resetting the color at the end of the line like so:

`echo "stuff with red background%{B#000000}stuff with black background%{B-}"`